# Flow picklist field outputs picklist field API name when there's no value

Tags: visual-workflow

In our Visual Flow, we have a screen for Generational Suffix, which is an optional picklist:

[image]

The `Generation_Suffix_Picklist_Choice` is a Picklist Choice showing value like "Sr.", "Jr.", etc. This works just fine.

The `Generational_Siffix_Default_Choice` is a standard choice field bound to the a `Contact` field called `Generational_Suffix__c`. Here is its setup:

[image]

When there's a value already set in this field, the Flow picklist field shows that value, as expected. But if the value is not set already, then the picklist show the API name of the picklist component itself:

[image]

How can I have it show blank or no value when the field is blank/null?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to write a formula that checks if your {!Contact.Generational_Suffix__c} is null. If yes, set it to something like "--None--". If no, set it to your merge field.

Comment: That would be `BLANKVALUE`, I think.